# Storing DateTime variable into local C# variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, formatexception

I believe my question may seem amateurish, but my objective is to take a `DateTime` data from my database and store it into a local variable. My code snippet has been added below:

```
string checkdu1 = "select Top 1 Date from CF";
SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(checkdu1, con);
SqlDataReader dru1 = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime("Date");          //error here
```

The database name is CF and the value of `Date` column is to be retrieved. But I am getting an

> exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

The datatype of `Date` in the database is `DateTime`.

I cannot find a proper answer and your help would be appreciated.

Comment: The parameter to Convert.ToDateTime should be the value you want to convert

Comment: Show what is in your Table in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to convert the word "Date" into a date, which isn't going to work.

Try something like

```
DateTime d1 = dru1.GetDateTime(dru1.GetOrdinal("Date"));
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and it is giving me an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Don't forget to do the `reader.Read()`. In this case `dru1.Read()`. It returns a `bool` so it would be wise to check that it was true before attempting to grab the data.

Comment: @TyCobb is correct. Alternatively, if your code snippet is representative of your actual code (i.e. one row with one column returned), you can forgo the whole `DataReader` stuff and just call `cmdd.ExecuteScalar` - this will return the first column of the first result, and you can then cast that to a DateTime, e.g. `d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(cmdd.ExecuteScalar());` (assuming that the SQL will always return a valid date)

Comment: Thank you for your help! The issue has been resolved. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you are not using `dru1` for anything.

Look up here how to use the reader [SqlDataReader Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Second, as your date field is of data type *DateTime*, it makes no sense to convert it; it is a date.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work `DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dru1["Date"]);`

Comment: Thank you for you help!!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options based on your code sample:

## 1 Using DataReader

```
string checkdu1 = "select Top 1 Date from CF";
SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(checkdu1, con);
SqlDataReader dru1 = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
DateTime d1;
if(dru1.Read()) d1 = dru1.GetDateTime(0);
```

## 2 Using ExecuteScalar

```
string checkdu1 = "select Top 1 Date from CF";
SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(checkdu1, con);
DateTime d1 = (DateTime) cmdd.ExecuteScalar();
```